# Creating PostgreSQL view by running subquery multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I currently have a sql statement working that aggregates some data to get a multiple row output (not simple max/min calculation) on a subset of a table that has the same id. The following snipped calculates the trips taken by a specific id based on when a location changes.

```
WITH id_locations AS (
    SELECT created_at, id, location
        FROM locations
        WHERE id = 1
), travel_locations AS (
    SELECT created_at, id, location, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY created_at) AS row_num
        FROM id_locations
        WHERE 
            created_at IN (
                SELECT min(created_at)
                    FROM id_locations
                    GROUP BY location
            ) OR created_at IN (
                SELECT max(created_at)
                    FROM id_locations
                    GROUP BY location
            )
)
SELECT a.id id, a.created_at departed_at, b.created_at arrived_at, a.location departure_location, b.location arrival_location
    FROM travel_locations AS a
    INNER JOIN travel_locations AS b
        ON a.row_num = b.row_num - 1
    WHERE a.location <> b.location;

Data
id          created_at  location 
1           1           1
1           2           1
1           3           2
1           4           2
1           5           5
1           6           5
1           7           5
1           8           5
2           1           1 
2           2           1 
2           3           1 
2           4           1 
2           5           3 
2           6           3 
2           7           3 
2           8           3 

Desired Output
id          departed_at arrived_at  departure_location  arrival_location
1           2           3           1                   2
1           4           5           2                   5
2           4           5           1                   3
```

I would like to create a view that contains the output of this sql statement, ran on every subset of the table grouped by id

Is there any way to do this with raw sql, or would I need to iterate over all the possible id's with some sql client, run the same query, and insert the result into a table for future reference?

I am using postgresql 9.6 for reference

Comment: Are your ids unique?

Comment: i think you are looking for `group by`. post some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: No, that probably wasn't the best column name for an example.. The id_group statement will most likely be many rows, and the statement I run requires that I am looking at a subset with exclusively one id

Comment: Edited to include an example of the actual code @vkp

Comment: If you take the WHERE clause out of your CTE and add "PARTITION BY id" to your window function, will that produce what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you show how you would partition by id? From reading on it, it sounds like the correct solution, but I can't figure out the syntax in this situation @rd_nielsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       max_created_at AS departed_at,
       next_created_at AS arrived_at,
       location AS departure_location,
       next_location AS arrival_location
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          created_at,
          location,
          max(created_at) over(partition by id,location) AS max_created_at,
          lead(created_at) over(partition by id order by location,created_at) AS next_created_at,
          lead(location) over(partition by id order by location,created_at) AS next_location
   FROM locations) t
WHERE max_created_at=created_at AND next_created_at IS NOT NULL
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/DNZ97332)**

What you're trying to get is the `max` created_at and the corresponding location and the next created_at,location for an id.

- Get the `max` created_at for each id,location using the `max` window function.
- Use `lead` to get location,created_at values from the next row (ordered by location,created_at) for each id.
- Get the rows where `max_created_at` equals the current row's created_at and next_created_at is not null.